# Converting ASN.1 DER to PEM file

Tags: openssl, pem, asn.1, der

Let's assume the following private key (in hex): `dd1cd59c4de2fa92e363dac282afe790a5193177d413b38e206b2b86b879ffbf`.

I would like to sign a message with this private key via openSSL. OpenSSL requires a pem file as key. So I'm trying to convert the above hex string to a PEM file.

As far as I realized so far, I need to do the following steps:

1. Add the following prefix to the hex string: `30740201010420`.
2. Add the following string after the hex string: `a00706052b8104000aa144034200`.
3. Add the public key

So I ended up with the following hex string: `30740201010420dd1cd59c4de2fa92e363dac282afe790a5193177d413b38e206b2b86b879ffbfa00706052b8104000aa144034200049d0f70eed85345ca5c1c04563bed19608562c37d644061785a836e8f199155f2818a1e2661f9ed501d8f906611892099a9de5a7ea9f641ecb4dd75bbb63c2d5a`.

I convert it to binary and base64 the result:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIN0c1ZxN4vqS42PawoKv55ClGTF31BOzjiBrK4a4ef+/oAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAEnQ9w7thTRcpcHARWO+0ZYIViw31kQGF4WoNujxmRVfKBih4mYfntUB2P
kGYRiSCZqd5afqn2Qey03XW7tjwtWg==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Is this the proper way of doing it? Is this a valid PEM key?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Maybe try [openssl convert der to pem](https://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+convert+der+to+pem). Its a lot less fragile than your method.

Comment: This question is not off-topic.
Filezilla Server on 1 side which use DER format
C#.NET X509Certificate2 class which use ASN.1 DER